# Remove permalink settings in post for users

Tags: permalinks, cms

I'm use the following code to remove the permalink settings in a post. This work until the user presses on publish button. Then the permalink settings reappear.

```
add_action('admin_head', 'wpds_custom_admin_post_css');
function wpds_custom_admin_post_css() {

    global $post_type;

    if ($post_type == 'post_type') {
        echo "<style>#edit-slug-box {display:none;}</style>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [default post types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Default_Post_Types) are post, page, attachment, revision, and nav_menu_item.

Replace 'post_type' with 'post':

```
add_action('admin_head', 'wpds_custom_admin_post_css');
function wpds_custom_admin_post_css() {

    global $post_type;

    if ($post_type == 'post') {
        echo "<style>#edit-slug-box {display:none;}</style>";
    }
}
```

If you want to remove it for multiple post types (i.e. post, page, or any custom post types you might have), change line #6 above:

```
     if ( in_array($post_type, array( 'post', 'page', 'your_own_post_type' )) ) {
```

If you only want to remove it from posts for non-admins, change line #6 above:

```
     if ( ($post_type == 'post') && (! current_user_can( 'administrator' )) ) {
```

Additionally, if you want to remove the slug meta box for posts, add:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'custom_remove_meta_boxes' );
function custom_remove_meta_boxes() {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) {
        remove_meta_box('slugdiv', 'post', 'normal');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I now see what I've done wrong. I work with custom post. I need to change the name of the post.

If I have multiple custom posts, do I need to add this add action again for each, or can I add the post IDs with a comma?

Comment: I updated answer above for multiple post types, see second code snippet. You can replace 'post', 'page', 'your_own_post_type', or add additional default or custom post types, in the array to check.